# Task not serializable: only due to a fixed String?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following RDD:

`myRDD:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]`

Then I want to add a fixed key:

`myRdd.map(("myFixedKey",_)):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector))]`

But if I use a constant String val instead of a hardcoded/explicit string:

`val myFixedKeyVal:String = "myFixedKey"
 myRdd.map((myFixedKeyVal,_))`

This previous line code gives the following exception:

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

Am I missing something?

**Solution:**

Ok I found the problem, `myRdd` is an object that extends a Serializable class, but after process this RDD by another class, e.g. `Process`:

```
class Process(someRdd:MyRddClass) extends Serializable{
   def preprocess = someRdd.map(_)
}
val someprocess = Process(myRdd)
val newRdd = someprocess.preprocess
newRdd.map(x=>("newkey",x)
```

This class `Process` must extend `Serializable` too in order to work. I thought that the newRdd was extending the root class `MyRddClass`...

Comment: Show us the whole listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string constant is not the problem. Turn on serialization debugging with `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` to figure out the real cause.